# Is there a way to always disable keyboard in a page?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a page where users can choose either they want to connect with social media or login with email. This page does not need any user input. So there is no need for keyboard.

```
  return Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    fit: StackFit.expand,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
          Colors.deepPurple,
          Colors.purple[700],
          Colors.purple
        ], begin: Alignment.topCenter, end: Alignment.bottomCenter)),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            _withSocialMedia,
            _or,
            _withEmail,
            SizedBox(height: 50.0),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

I have 2 questions related to this page.

1. Is there a way that i can always disable keyboard from popping up in
   this page?
2. Is there a way for me to make the page does not push
   all the elements in the page to the top to accommodate keyboard?

Hopefully you guys can help me on this. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any focusable widget in your code. What is causing the keyboard to show up?

Comment: The keyboard is coming from the previous page

Answer (score 1):

Put this in a utility file somewhere and call whenever you need to dismiss the keyboard programmatically. In your case, it would be just before navigating away from the previous screen.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

/// Hides the onscreen keyboard
void hideKeyboard(BuildContext context) {
  SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
}
```